# Selecting distinct record id after joining table

Tags: sql, join, distinct

i have got two table that i used inner join. ArticleDetail and my temp table #tempexceptionBag

```
Select [Country],[Date],[Location] ,[Article],[Colour],b.Size ,b.Barcode
  ,[SoldQty],[UnitCost],[GrossPrice],[Netprice],[NetpriceSGD],[TransactionID],[StaffID],[UploadFlagUpdated]
  ,[RecordID]
from #tempexceptionBag a
inner join CK_DW..ArticleDetail b
on a.Article = b.Articleno
and right('0' + a.Colour,2) = right('0' + b.Color_code,2)
where a.size is not null
```

This command will results me is having repeated recordid... how do i select the unique recordid?
I try using

`Select Distinct [Country],[Date],[Location] ,[Article],[Colour],b.Size ,b.Barcode
      ,[SoldQty],[UnitCost],[GrossPrice],[Netprice],[NetpriceSGD],[TransactionID],[StaffID],[UploadFlagUpdated]
      ,[RecordID]
    from #tempexceptionBag a
    inner join CK_DW..ArticleDetail b
    on a.Article = b.Articleno
    and right('0' + a.Colour,2) = right('0' + b.Color_code,2)
    where a.size is not null`

but the results i will still get repeated recordid

example result

```
> Country   Date         Location            Article     Colour Size    Barcode     SoldQty UnitCost    GrossPrice  Netprice    NetpriceSGD TransactionID   StaffID UploadFlagUpdated   RecordID

INDONESIA   20/4/2014     BAZAR BANDUNG    CK2-10680039   22    XS      1001025022328   1   167769      339000      209000       22.82       BZ02359         NULL      0                30711547
INDONESIA   20/4/2014     BAZAR BANDUNG    CK2-10680039   22    XS      1001025022328   1   167769      339000      209000       22.82       BZ02436         NULL      0                30711547
INDONESIA   20/4/2014     BAZAR BANDUNG    CK2-10680050   1     XS      1001107201320   1   154845      349000      209000       22.82       BZ02136         NULL      0                30711551
INDONESIA   20/4/2014     BAZAR BANDUNG    CK2-10680073   6     XS      1001226106322   1   186402      419000      299000       32.66       BZ02231         NULL      0                30711560
```

but what i want is

```
   Country  Date         Location            Article     Colour Size    Barcode     SoldQty UnitCost    GrossPrice  Netprice    NetpriceSGD TransactionID   StaffID UploadFlagUpdated   RecordID

INDONESIA   20/4/2014     BAZAR BANDUNG    CK2-10680039   22    XS      1001025022328   1   167769      339000      209000       22.82       BZ02436         NULL      0                30711547
INDONESIA   20/4/2014     BAZAR BANDUNG    CK2-10680050   1     XS      1001107201320   1   154845      349000      209000       22.82       BZ02136         NULL      0                30711551
INDONESIA   20/4/2014     BAZAR BANDUNG    CK2-10680073   6     XS      1001226106322   1   186402      419000      299000       32.66       BZ02231         NULL      0                30711560
```

ADDITIONAL

after trying out

`select [Country],[Date],[Location] ,[Article],[Colour],b.Size ,b.Barcode,[SoldQty],[UnitCost],[GrossPrice],[Netprice],[NetpriceSGD],[TransactionID],[StaffID],[UploadFlagUpdated],COUNT([RecordID]) As num_Recordid
from #tempexceptionBag a
inner join CK_DW..ArticleDetail b
on a.Article = b.Articleno
and right('0' + a.Colour,2) = right('0' + b.Color_code,2)
where a.size is not nullgroup by [Country],[Date],[Location] ,[Article],[Colour],b.Size ,b.Barcode
      ,[SoldQty],[UnitCost],[GrossPrice],[Netprice],[NetpriceSGD],[StaffID],[TransactionID],[UploadFlagUpdated]`

I couldnt get the recordid displayed

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be very helpful if you add an example of the results you expect yo get, and an example of the results you get right now. also, providing a demo in [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8) Will be helpful as well.

Comment: i have added the sample data

Comment: +1 For adding sample data.

Comment: For `Colour` 22 you have 2 values for `BZ02359`. In your results, how can you tell which one is the one you want to get?

Comment: eh i need to look at the recordid instead of transactionid.. i want to get the first one that it occur  `30711547`

Comment: try a group by instead of distinct when using join

Answer (score 0):

You are getting duplicates because you are including transactions in an inventory query If you exclude TransactionID it will provide enough uniqueness for DISTINCT to give you the results you expect.

You can also aggregate the transactions to get a count of transactions for that item. e.g.

```
SELECT 
     [Country]
    ,[Date]
    ,[Location]
    ,[Article]
    ,[Colour]
    ,b.Size
    ,b.Barcode
    ,[SoldQty]
    ,[UnitCost]
    ,[GrossPrice]
    ,[Netprice]
    ,[NetpriceSGD]
    ,[StaffID]
    ,[UploadFlagUpdated]
    ,[RecordID]
    ,COUNT([TransactionID]) AS num_transactions
FROM #tempexceptionBag a
    INNER JOIN CK_DW..ArticleDetail b ON a.Article = b.Articleno
        AND right('0' + a.Colour, 2) = right('0' + b.Color_code, 2)
WHERE a.size IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY [Country]
        ,[Date]
        ,[Location]
        ,[Article]
        ,[Colour]
        ,b.Size
        ,b.Barcode
        ,[SoldQty]
        ,[UnitCost]
        ,[GrossPrice]
        ,[Netprice]
        ,[NetpriceSGD]
        ,[StaffID]
        ,[UploadFlagUpdated]
        ,[RecordID]
```

Alternately, if you want one column containing all the transaction IDs you can select them as an xml string. You can then use the STUFF function to nicely format it. I'm not somewhere I can test it right now, so you might need to sanity check my query, but it would be something like:

```
SELECT 
     [Country]
    ,[Date]
    ,[Location]
    ,[Article]
    ,[Colour]
    ,b.Size
    ,b.Barcode
    ,[SoldQty]
    ,[UnitCost]
    ,[GrossPrice]
    ,[Netprice]
    ,[NetpriceSGD]
    ,[StaffID]
    ,[UploadFlagUpdated]
    ,[RecordID]
    ,(STUFF((
                SELECT
                    TransactionID
                FROM #tempexceptionBag ia
                    INNER JOIN CK_DW..ArticleDetail ib ON ia.Article = ib.Articleno
                        AND right('0' + ia.Colour, 2) = right('0' + ib.Color_code, 2)
                WHERE ia.size IS NOT NULL
                    AND a.Article = ia.Article
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 2, ''
            )
      ) AS TransactionIDs
FROM #tempexceptionBag a
    INNER JOIN CK_DW..ArticleDetail b ON a.Article = b.Articleno
        AND right('0' + a.Colour, 2) = right('0' + b.Color_code, 2)
WHERE a.size IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY [Country]
        ,[Date]
        ,[Location]
        ,[Article]
        ,[Colour]
        ,b.Size
        ,b.Barcode
        ,[SoldQty]
        ,[UnitCost]
        ,[GrossPrice]
        ,[Netprice]
        ,[NetpriceSGD]
        ,[StaffID]
        ,[UploadFlagUpdated]
        ,[RecordID]
```

The idea behind that is to do an in-line query as an XML string, e.g.

```
SELECT  
     ( SELECT
            ', ' + CAST(surrogate_key AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS [text()]
        FROM dimension IDIM
        WHERE IDIM.code = DIM.code
        FOR XML PATH('')
     )
    ,code
FROM dimension DIM
WHERE code LIKE 'Code With Duplicates'
GROUP BY code
```

This gives you the results, then STUFF just formats it

```
SELECT  
     (STUFF((SELECT
                    ', ' + CAST(surrogate_key AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS [text()]
                FROM dimension IDIM
                WHERE IDIM.code = DIM.code
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 2, ''
            )
     )
    ,code
FROM dimension DIM
WHERE code LIKE 'Code With Duplicates'
GROUP BY code
```

If you want just the first transactionID to appear for that Article, you could use ROW_NUMBER(), then wrap it in another select.

```
SELECT
     [Country]
    ,[Date]
    ,[Location]
    ,[Article]
    ,[Colour]
    ,b.Size
    ,b.Barcode
    ,[SoldQty]
    ,[UnitCost]
    ,[GrossPrice]
    ,[Netprice]
    ,[NetpriceSGD]
    ,[StaffID]
    ,[UploadFlagUpdated]
    ,[RecordID]
    ,TransactionID
FROM(
    SELECT 
         [Country]
        ,[Date]
        ,[Location]
        ,[Article]
        ,[Colour]
        ,b.Size
        ,b.Barcode
        ,[SoldQty]
        ,[UnitCost]
        ,[GrossPrice]
        ,[Netprice]
        ,[NetpriceSGD]
        ,[StaffID]
        ,[UploadFlagUpdated]
        ,[RecordID]
        ,TransactionID
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                        PARTITION BY Article 
                        ORDER BY TransactionID
                        ) SEQ
    FROM #tempexceptionBag a
        INNER JOIN CK_DW..ArticleDetail b ON a.Article = b.Articleno
            AND right('0' + a.Colour, 2) = right('0' + b.Color_code, 2)
    WHERE a.size IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY [Country]
            ,[Date]
            ,[Location]
            ,[Article]
            ,[Colour]
            ,b.Size
            ,b.Barcode
            ,[SoldQty]
            ,[UnitCost]
            ,[GrossPrice]
            ,[Netprice]
            ,[NetpriceSGD]
            ,[StaffID]
            ,[UploadFlagUpdated]
            ,[RecordID]
) I
WHERE SEQ = 1
```

Comment: This looks good because the duplications are caused by the [TransactionID] for the first 2 records in the dataset you provided. Removing [TransactionID] as the above makes all records DISTINCT to the [RecordID]

Comment: i got this error.. Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator...and will this work if i gt like transactionID that can be similar.. becos the onli unique column will be the recordID

Comment: I foolishly posted it as I was running out the door, sorry. You want to use COUNT(TransactionID)

Comment: hi Tsarin, i tried using count.. but this way.. i cant have the recordid displayed?

Comment: oh ya.. i realised that even using tt code.. i was still getting repeating RecordID.. in my case.. TransactionID can be repeated but i need unique recordid

Comment: Without uniqueness across all columns, you won't be able to get unique rows. So the only way you can keep TransactionID in the results is to put all transactions which match that record into a single column. I have updated the answer with an example. I apologise if it doesn't execute, so I have added a breakdown of what it is below the full query.